# How to get all missing numbers from id column

Tags: mysql, database

Users table has id field in mysql database, and table has below record in id field

|id|

```
2
3
5
6
9
10
15
16
18
21
25
```

I want to get missing records row like below:-

```
1
4
7
8
11
12
13
14
17
19
20
22
23
24
```

Comment: MySQL version??

Answer (score 2):

How cool is this ?

```
SELECT seq.`id` FROM (
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as `id`
FROM `users` t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
CROSS JOIN `users` t2
) as seq WHERE seq.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `users`) 
AND seq.`id` <= (SELECT max(`id`) from `users`);
```

If you want the missing ids for analytical purpose, should love this one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(dt.missing, IF(dt.`found`-1 > dt.missing, CONCAT(' to ', dt.`found` - 1), '')) AS missing
FROM ( SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS `missing`,
    IF (@rownum=id, 0, @rownum:=id) AS `found`
 FROM ( SELECT @rownum:=0 ) AS r
 JOIN users
 ORDER BY id ) AS dt
WHERE dt.`found`!= 0;
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Please try to find, and also let me know where it is :)

Comment: Side Note: Try to appraise/upvote/appreciate ones work, not everyone here is a copy&paste horse.

Answer (score -1):

Use a calendar table approach and anti-join approach:

```
CREATE TABLE nums (id INT);
INSERT INTO nums (id)
(
    SELECT (t*10+u+1) x FROM
    (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
     SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
    (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
     SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
);

SELECT
    n.id
FROM nums n
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON n.id = u.id
WHERE
    u.id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    n.id;
```

### Demo

Note that in the demo and query I did not limit the height of the range of missing numbers which gets returned.  I arbitrarily used a sequence of numbers 1..100, but you may restrict to any size you want.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, is there any solution using only users table

Comment: Why not?  Can you give a solution which does not do this?

Comment: I was not able to do this that's why I asked this question, I am not doing the marketing but you can see the second example of "Bilal Siddiqui"